# Request mapping using headers in Spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

Currently I am using Spring mvc request mapping using headers.

Following are the two methods I have:

Method 1:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts", method = RequestMethod.GET,
headers="Accept=application/vnd.se.company1.product1+json; version=2.0")

@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> loginVerionOne(final HttpServletRequest request){}
```

Method 2:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts", method = RequestMethod.GET,
headers="Accept=application/vnd.se.company1.product1+json; version=3.0")

@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> loginVersionTwo(final HttpServletRequest request) {}
```

The problem here is that when client sends accept header in it's request in below format:
`Accept=application/vnd.se.company1.product1+json; version=3.0`

Then spring maps to the first method only even if the version is 3.0.
I have read in one of the post that spring ignores request mapping after <kbd>;</kbd> (semi-colon) in request mapping using headers.

We are using custom accept header where we need to keep content type and version separately.

The mapping works if I use Accept header in below format:
`Accept=application/vnd.se.company1.product1.v2.0+json`

But I do not want to use above format.
Any help in this issue will be appreciated.

Following is my code used :

```
RequestMappingController
========================
@RequestMapping(value = "/helloworld",method=RequestMethod.GET)
        @SubdomainMapping(subdomains="application/vnd.se.company1.product1+json;version=2.0")
    public ModelAndView helloWordNew(HttpServletRequest req){
         String message = "Hello World Version 2.0";
         return new ModelAndView("helloworld", "message",message);
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/helloworld",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @SubdomainMapping(subdomains="application/vnd.se.company1.product1+json;version=3.0")
    public ModelAndView helloWord(HttpServletRequest req){
          String message = "Hello World Version 3.0";
          return new ModelAndView("helloworld", "message",message);
    }

RequestCondition:
================

public class SubdomainRequestCondition implements
        RequestCondition<SubdomainRequestCondition> {

    private final Set<String> subdomains;


    public SubdomainRequestCondition(String subdomains) {
        this(Arrays.asList(subdomains));
    }

    public SubdomainRequestCondition(Collection<String> subdomains) {
        this.subdomains = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<String>(
                subdomains));
    }

    @Override
    public SubdomainRequestCondition combine(SubdomainRequestCondition other) {
        Set<String> allRoles = new LinkedHashSet<String>(this.subdomains);
        allRoles.addAll(other.subdomains);
        return new SubdomainRequestCondition(allRoles);
    }

    @Override
    public SubdomainRequestCondition getMatchingCondition(
            HttpServletRequest request) {
            String header = request.getHeader("Accept");
            for (String s : subdomains) {
                if (s.equals(header)) {
                    return this;
                }
            }
        return null;
    }

   @Override
    public int compareTo(SubdomainRequestCondition other,
            HttpServletRequest request) {
        return org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.removeAll(other.subdomains, this.subdomains).size();
    }
}

HandlerMapping
==============

public class CustomRequestMappingHandlerMapping extends
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping {
   @Override
    protected RequestCondition<?> getCustomTypeCondition(Class<?> handlerType) {
        SubdomainMapping typeAnnotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(
                handlerType, SubdomainMapping.class);
        return createCondition(typeAnnotation);
    }

    @Override
    protected RequestCondition<?> getCustomMethodCondition(Method method) {
        SubdomainMapping methodAnnotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(
                method, SubdomainMapping.class);
        return createCondition(methodAnnotation);
    }

    private RequestCondition<?> createCondition(SubdomainMapping accessMapping) {
        return (accessMapping != null) ? new SubdomainRequestCondition(accessMapping.subdomains()) : null;
    }
}



   applicationContext.xml
    ======================
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.net.controllers"/>

        <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

            <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean name="handlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
            <property name="webBindingInitializer">
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
               <property name="validator">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        </bean>
<bean id="re" class="com.net.controllers.WebConfig"/>
</beans>

WebConfig.java
==============

@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Autowired

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        CustomRequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new CustomRequestMappingHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setOrder(0);
        handlerMapping.setInterceptors(getInterceptors());
        return handlerMapping;
    }

     @Bean
        @Override
        public FormattingConversionService mvcConversionService() {

            // Use the DefaultFormattingConversionService but do not register defaults
            DefaultFormattingConversionService conversionService = new DefaultFormattingConversionService(false);
            return conversionService;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are special properties for content negotiation: `consumes` and `produces`. In your case it would be

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts", method = RequestMethod.GET,
produces="application/vnd.se.company1.product1+json; version=2.0")
```

That does not solve your problem though. Spring only considers the media type and the subtype when looking for a match. That's a hard coded behavior.

I can offer two solutions:

**Solution 1**

Map to the media type only and have separate private methods. Something like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts", method = RequestMethod.GET,
produces="application/vnd.se.company1.product1+json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> login(final HttpServletRequest request){
   if(getVersion(request).equals(VERSION_2)) {
     loginVersion2(request);
```

**Solution 2**

Implement your own mapping condition. It's not difficult but there is no reference in the official docs. You would have to google for `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.RequestCondition`

Comment: I have gone through some more posts and found out that using RequestMappingHandlerMapping class we can write our own condition for request mapping. But for this I need to use Spring MVC Java-based configuration and we are using applicationContext.xml and not Java based configuration. Any idea how can I proceed on this?

Comment: @ManasiD You write your own class extending `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and configure the bean in your xml like `<bean id="handlerMapping" class = "org.example.MyHandlerMapping" />`

Comment: So there will be both xml configuration as well as java based configuration right? I have done that and I get error Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getUrlPathHelper()Lorg/springframework/web/util/UrlPathHelper;

Comment: @ManasiD You wrote that you only have an `applicationContext.xml`. You don't need an additional Java based configuration. You can look at [this example](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-mvc-31-demo/tree/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc31/requestcondition/mvc) for an implementation.

Comment: yes I am referring above example only. In this example there is a class WebConfig where requestMappingHandlerMapping() method is overridden. So I have injected WebConfig class in my applicationContext.xml. From some of the posts I have gone through I understand that for custom request mapping we need to have a java based configuration.

Comment: @ManasiD You don't need the `WebConfig` class.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt replies. I am new to spring. How can I create the same behaviour that is done using WebConfig class? Do I need to just inject my ExtendedRequestMappingHandlerMapping class via xml? I get below error after injecting bean :java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMappi‌​ng.getUrlPathHelper()Lorg/springframework/web/util/UrlPathHelper

Comment: I have configured using suggested above example. But depending upon header value annotation solition is not working. e.g if my Annotation is above my method @HeaderMapping("application/vnd.se.company1.product1+json; version=2.0") and @HeaderMapping("application/vnd.se.company1.product1+json; version=3.0") Request still gets mapped to first method annotation regardless of annotation. Please suggest.

Comment: Please add your code, in particular the handler mapping, the request condition and the part of your `applicationContext.xml` where you add it. And be sure to remove the `headers` value from your `@RequestMapping`.

Comment: I am not able to put all my code in this comment. Please let me know how to add this as I am new to stack overflow.

Comment: @ManasiD below your question you have an `edit` link. You can add the code to your question.

Comment: @ManasiD `if (s.equals(header)) {` in your `getMatchingCondition()` method may not always give you the expected result. Your `@SubDomainMapping` contains no space before `version=`. Your `@RequestMapping`does, so I guess it comes in with a space in which case the method will return `null`. For now just make sure that the value in your `@SubDomainMapping` **exactly** matches the header of the request.

Comment: Yes in my request I am sending Accept header as application/vnd.se.company1.product1+json;version=2.0 with no space and @SubDomainMapping also does not have space. The values are matched properly but it seems custom request mapping does not work.

Comment: @ManasiD In this case I suggest to debug your application and set breakpoints in the `getCustomMethodCondition` and the `getMatchingCondition` methods to see if they are called at all and work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

separate the two headers with a comma :

```
headers = {"Accept=application/vnd.se.company1.product1+json", "version=3.0"})
```

Comment: But Accept=application/vnd.se.company1.product1+json; version=2.0" this is part of a one header. These are not two different headers.

Comment: @ManasiD no it isn't.

Comment: I get below error: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException: No matching handler method found for servlet request: path '/accounts', method 'GET', parameters map[[empty]] by using above header.